# The Badge number is constantly increasing, even after I use the setBadgeNumber(0) method

Tags: air, push-notification, air-native-extension, ane, distriqt

I'm using the Distriqt PushNotifications ANE and PARSE to send PushNotifications, and so far everything is working PERFECTLY.

This means, I register my iOS devices and receive PushNotifications as it should be....

When I send PushNotifications with PARSE I use the badge:"Increment" value, which understandably increments the Value By +1.

After I open the App, I want to reset the BADGE to be at 0 and I use the setBadgeNumber(0) method... This also works, I tried with other values like 11, or 1 and it displays it correctly.

The Problem is that when I send another PARSE notification it displays now the old value + 1 !!!

Like so:

- I use PARSE to send 3 PushNotifications
- The badge displays (3)
- I use the setBadgeNumber(0)
- The badge displays (0)
- I use PARSE to send 2 additional PushNotifications
- The badge displays (5)!!!!

How can I really reset the badge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the badge is actually sent as part of the push notification payload, eg:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Notification content",
        "badge" : 5
    }
}
```

You should double check what Parse is actually sending as it will be keeping a count of the notifications and sending that as part of the payload, so you will either need to disable this in Parse or notify Parse of your user resetting / changing the count.

Calling `setBadgeNumber` just changes the icon on the application and doesn't update Parse of this change.

You could look into the Parse ANE which helps out with this process:

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Parse